# Capistrano 3 + nginx setup: 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

I am deploying my app via Capistrano 3 to a Ubuntu server, the deployment process goes through well without any issues, but when I load my website (IP), I only get the error message **502 Bad Gateway**.

My setup:

**deploy.rb**:

```
lock "3.8.1"

set :application, "project"
set :repo_url, "git@bitbucket.org:username/project.git"
set :branch, "master"
set :tmp_dir, '/home/deployer/tmp'

#set :rvm_type, :user                     # Defaults to: :auto
#set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.4.0'      # Defaults to: 'default'

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
# set :deploy_to, "/var/www/my_app_name"

# Default value for :format is :airbrussh.
# set :format, :airbrussh

# You can configure the Airbrussh format using :format_options.
# These are the defaults.
# set :format_options, command_output: true, log_file: "log/capistrano.log", color: :auto, truncate: :auto

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
# append :linked_files, "config/database.yml", "config/secrets.yml"

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "public/system"

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 5


set(:executable_config_files, %w(
  unicorn_init.sh
))

# files which need to be symlinked to other parts of the
# filesystem. For example nginx virtualhosts, log rotation
# init scripts etc.
set(:symlinks, [
  {
    source: "nginx.conf",
    link: "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default}"
  },
  {
    source: "unicorn_init.sh",
    link: "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{fetch(:application)}"
  },
  {
    source: "log_rotation",
   link: "/etc/logrotate.d/#{fetch(:application)}"
  },
  {
    source: "monit",
    link: "/etc/monit/conf.d/#{fetch(:application)}.conf"
  }
])



namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Stop Unicorn'
  task :stop do
    on roles(:app) do
      if test("[ -f #{fetch(:unicorn_pid)} ]")
        execute :kill, capture(:cat, fetch(:unicorn_pid))
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Start Unicorn'
  task :start do
    on roles(:app) do
      within current_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :bundle, "exec unicorn -c #{fetch(:unicorn_config)} -D"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Reload Unicorn without killing master process'
  task :reload do
    on roles(:app) do
      if test("[ -f #{fetch(:unicorn_pid)} ]")
        execute :kill, '-s USR2', capture(:cat, fetch(:unicorn_pid))
      else
        error 'Unicorn process not running'
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart Unicorn'
  task :restart
  before :restart, :stop
  before :restart, :start

=begin
  task :setup_config do
    on roles(:app) do
      sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default"
      sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
      run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
      put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
      puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
    end
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config do
    on roles(:app) do
      run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
    end
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"
=end
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:web) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

**unicorn.rb**

```
root = "/home/deployer/apps/project/current"
working_directory root

pid "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"

stderr_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"

worker_processes Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'])
timeout 30
preload_app true

listen '/tmp/unicorn.project.sock', backlog: 64

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end

# Force the bundler gemfile environment variable to
# reference the capistrano "current" symlink
before_exec do |_|
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = File.join(root, 'Gemfile')
end
```

on the server: **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.project.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  # server_name example.com;
  root /home/deployer/apps/project/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location ~ ^/(robots.txt|sitemap.xml.gz)/ {
    root /home/deployer/apps/project/current/public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

error log from **/var/log/nginx/error.log**:

```
2017/07/26 06:57:55 [crit] 25631#25631: *1879 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: IP, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.project.sock:/500.html", host: "IP", referrer: "http://IP/"
```

How do I solve this error message? I checked the paths, it should be correct, not typos etc.

Also, don't I miss anything (symlinks?) in **deploy.rb** to "refresh" the **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default** file?

Thank you for every advance.

Comment: When I log in on the server and run `sudo service unicorn_prioject start`, I get the error `Failed to start unicorn_project.service: Unit unicorn_project.service not found.`

Comment: And when I go to the directory where my app is on the server and run `bundle exec unicorn -D -c /home/deployer/apps/[roject/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production`, I get  `bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/unicorn)
ArgumentError: directory for pid=/home/deployer/apps/project/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid not writable...`

Comment: does directory `pids` exist inside tmp ? and does it have required permissions ?